# Connecting mySQL to MSSQL

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, database, sql

I need a little advise, I need to sync a DB that is currently on a Server 2008(SQL Server 2005) machine and I use Studio Express to connect to it. I need a way of syncing this DB to mysql that lives on a NAS on the same network:

Local: DB Engine on server, named, server\sqlexpress and IP = 10.0.0.201

Target: DB on NAS, named, CISCO-NAS and IP = 10.0.0.182

Will need for this to sync every few mins...

I really don't know how to start.

Answer (score 0):

One of many ways is to get the mysql odbc installer and install it on you sql2008 server then create an etl job to complete the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford, I suggest that you use Oracle Goldengate which targets this sort of things. I used to be an Oracle DB admin a long long time ago and otherwise have no relation to them. Or else you can just export sql, massage the data, and import yourself (you can stream the delta changes to make it look like synching). The effort in that case depends how much your schemas differ and how much nonstandard SQL you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some GUI clients like SQLyog. Where you can import data from SQL Server to MySQL.